# BGL. Shortest path with calculating the weights of edges on the go?

Tags: boost, boost-graph

I am trying to build a full graph on a set of points with coordinates (with weights on edges equal to their lengths) and then to find a shortest path between two specific points. Is there a way to calculate the weights of the edges during the run of the *`dijkstra_shortest_paths()`*?

I could calculate them when building the graph, but I want to be able to change the coordinates of the points and to recalculate the shortest path without rebuilding the graph.

Answer (score 0):

The property map used for the edge weights can be arbitrary, and so in particular it can be a `function_property_map` ([documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/property_map/doc/function_property_map.html)) that computes the weights in an arbitrary way.  You can also look at `libs/graph/example/implicit_graph.cpp` for how to manually create a weight map; you do not need a custom graph class to have a custom property map to pass into an algorithm, however.